# swift 2.0 healthkit requestAuthorizationToShareTypes - Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: swift2, healthkit

after converting from swift 1.2 to 2.0 I get the following error:
 Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
when I request for authorisation as follow:

```
healthKitStore.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(writeTypes: healthKitTypesToWrite, readTypes: healthKitTypesToRead,completion:  { success, error in
        if success {
            print("SUCCESS")
        } else {
            print(error.description)
        }
        })
```

any ideas?

Comment: I would fix the println() and try again (println() is illegal in Swift 2.0 AFAK and should be print()).  Post the resulting error string.  It will be more helpful if you format the code using the 'code' tool in StackOverflow interface.

Comment: I already corrected the println to print, the error is not related to that anyway, I'm correcting the example I put to avoid misleading info

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally fixed the problem, and not sure it has anything to do with the error message itself.

1) healthKitTypesToRead and write: removed the [ ] from Set ( [ ] )

2) created a new completion duple

3) changed the call as follow bellow

example:

```
let healthKitTypesToRead = Set(
        arrayLiteral: HKObjectType.characteristicTypeForIdentifier(HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierDateOfBirth)!,
        HKObjectType.characteristicTypeForIdentifier(HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBiologicalSex)!,
        HKObjectType.workoutType()
        )

let newCompletion: ((Bool, NSError?) -> Void) = {
        (success, error) -> Void in

        if !success {
            print("You didn't allow HealthKit to access these write data types.\nThe error was:\n \(error!.description).")

            return
        }
    }


healthKitStore.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(healthKitTypesToWrite, readTypes: healthKitTypesToRead, completion: newCompletion)
```

now the code compiles properly